# Where to look when the system crashes or something else horrible goes down?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, crash, logging, linux-mint

My Linux Mint workstation is acting funky, it appears to be logging me out randomly, though I'm guessing what's really happening is that the X desktop is crashing. Maybe.

How do I troubleshoot this?

I'm not sure which log file to look at. I tried looking at `dmesg` and `Xorg.log` in `/var/log` but I'm not sure what to look for. Not to mention there are no conventional timestamps, but a string like `[    0.416674]` and I have no idea what that means.

Comment: Well, do not use X for a while, and check if the system still acts "funky". It is high time time get used to the console :-)
And if you have gazillion times, install a second OS, say, Ubuntu besides Mint and check if that fails as well (just to stay in the field of comparative bugfixing)

Comment: Not really practical advice unfortunately. I have work to do and it relies on using X/Gnome. Plus it's entirely random so I can't really predict when it'll show up.

Comment: Are you applying all available updates?

Comment: @ultrasawblade Within reason. Using mintUpdate only, not using apt-get and installing kernel updates, etc. But yes, everything is up to date.

Comment: I'd grep your logs for "error". dmesg, /var/log/syslog, Xorg.log seem like good places to start. If push comes to shove, I'd try doing another Linux install in parallel in an effort to see if it's a hardware problem. You should probably run memtest86 too...

Comment: Urgh. Known bug in Ubuntu and unresolved. Awesome. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg-server/+bug/778490

Answer (score 4):

These four files are your best bet.

```
/var/log/Xorg.0.log

/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

~/.xsession-errors

/var/log/messages
```

Comment: Those log files are rather large, use  `last |head -n 50` to get the timestamps of your crashes to save your self a lot of reading.

Comment: BUT WHICH ONE?!? WHICH ONE?!?!?!?!?

Comment: There also seems to be...: `/var/crash/`, `/var/log/syslog.#[.gz]`, and a whole bunch of other logs in `/var/log/`...

Answer (score 3):

After doing some research, seems like (for whatever reason), any recent X crashes show up in /var/log/Xorg.0.log.old

Comment: I guess that the .old log file relates to a terminated X11 session, because the new (currently running) one has to log stuff somewhere too.